# Merging multiple files into one within Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I get multiple small files into my input directory which I want to merge into a single file without using the local file system or writing mapreds. Is there a way I could do it using hadoof fs commands or Pig?

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept an answer if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 23):

In order to keep everything on the grid use hadoop streaming with a single reducer and cat as the mapper and reducer (basically a noop) - add compression using MR flags.

```
hadoop jar \
    $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming.jar \<br>
    -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
    -Dmapred.job.queue.name=$QUEUE \
    -input "$INPUT" \
    -output "$OUTPUT" \
    -mapper cat \
    -reducer cat
```

If you want compression add
  -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
-Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

Comment: I think it is the best method.

Comment: I imagine this would change the order of the lines?

Comment: @AndredeMiranda I think the order will be deterministic, sorted by key, since we only have one reducer. This is based on recalling the shuffle, sort, reducer model.

Comment: it's not jsut the best answer; it is the answer. all other answers are not correct (e.g. fs -getmerge will put file locally, not on hdfs )

Comment: Uhm, doing that adds a tabulation at the end of each line... how should we fix that?

Answer (score 17):

```
hadoop fs -getmerge <dir_of_input_files> <mergedsinglefile>
```

Comment: oddly this gives me no result. not sure why.

Comment: maybe your directory only has empty files

Comment: I think `mergedsinglefile` is local, not distributed

Comment: this will result with files on the local filesystem, which the OP wants to avoid

Comment: This does not put the file to hdfs, rather saves it to dfs. We then need to put the file back to hdfs using hdfs -put.

Answer (score 7):

okay...I figured out a way using `hadoop fs` commands -

```
hadoop fs -cat [dir]/* | hadoop fs -put - [destination file]
```

It worked when I tested it...any pitfalls one can think of?

Thanks!

Comment: But in this case you're downloading all data from HDFS to the node you're running command from (local one?), and then upload it to HDFS. This is not too effective if you have much of data

Comment: Another pitfall is that occasionally you might get also some unwanted input from stdin. I came across it once in an HA enabled cluster when some warning messages got trapped into the output.

Answer (score 4):

If you set up fuse to mount your HDFS to a local directory, then your output can be the mounted filesystem.

For example, I have our HDFS mounted to `/mnt/hdfs` locally. I run the following command and it works great:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /reports/some_output /mnt/hdfs/reports/some_output.txt
```

Of course, there are other reasons to use fuse to mount HDFS to a local directory, but this was a nice side effect for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [HDFSConcat](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/HDFSConcat.html), new in HDFS 0.21, to perform this operation without incurring the cost of a copy.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, will look into HDFSConcat. Currently we are on 0.20.2 so I am now creating a Har of all the files and then reading from pig. This way data stays in HDFS.

Comment: I should note that this tool has limitations highlighted at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-950. Files must have the same block size and be owned by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Hortonworks cluster and want to merge multiple file present in HDFS location into a single file then you can run 'hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar' jar which runs single reducer and get the merged file into HDFS output location.

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar \
-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
-input "/hdfs/input/dir" \
-output "/hdfs/output/dir" \
-mapper cat \
-reducer cat
```

You can download this jar from
[Get hadoop streaming jar](https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-streaming)

If you are writing spark jobs and want to get a merged file to avoid multiple RDD creations and performance bottlenecks use this piece of code before transforming your RDD

`sc.textFile("hdfs://...../part*).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...../filename)`

This will merge all part files into one and save it again into hdfs location

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions are equivalent to doing a

```
hadoop fs -cat [dir]/* > tmp_local_file  
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal tmp_local_file
```

it only means that the local m/c I/O is on the critical path of data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing this from Apache Pig perspective,

To merge two files with identical schema via Pig, UNION command can be used

```
 A = load 'tmp/file1' Using PigStorage('\t') as ....(schema1)
 B = load 'tmp/file2' Using PigStorage('\t') as ....(schema1) 
 C = UNION A,B
 store C into 'tmp/fileoutput' Using PigStorage('\t')
```