# Hadoop HDFS Copy Files from multiple folders to one destination folder

Tags: hadoop, command, hdfs

What is the effective way to copy smaller files from multiple HDFS folders to one destination folder? The smaller files also need to be merged for Map-Reduce to be effective.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548259/merging-multiple-files-into-one-within-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

There is [DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/distcp.html) which is an map-reduce job which copies files from one or multiple source folders to one target folder in an parallel manner.
However, its not merging files. 
But maybe you could use [filecrush](http://www.jointhegrid.com/hadoop_filecrush/index.jsp) to do that! (let me know how this goes!)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run default Map-Reduce job (with default Mapper and Reducer) with "multiple HDFS folders" as input and one destination folder as output.