# Merging small files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a directory (Final Dir) in HDFS in which some files(ex :10 mb) are loading every minute. 
After some time i want to combine all the small files to a large file(ex :100 mb). But the user is continuously pushing files to Final Dir. it is a continuous process.

So for the first time i need to combine the first 10 files to a large file (ex : large.txt) and save file to Finaldir.

Now my question is how i will get the next 10 files excluding the first 10 files?

can some please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging multiple files into one within Hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548259/merging-multiple-files-into-one-within-hadoop)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one more alternate, this is still the legacy approach pointed out by @Andrew in his comments but  with extra steps of  making your input folder as a buffer to receive small files pushing them to a tmp directory in a timely fashion and merging them and pushing the result back to input.

step 1 : create a tmp directory

```
hadoop fs -mkdir tmp
```

step 2 : move all the small files to the tmp directory at a point of time

```
hadoop fs -mv input/*.txt tmp
```

step 3 -merge the small files with the help of hadoop-streaming jar

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar \
                   -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
                   -input "/user/abc/input" \
                   -output "/user/abc/output" \
                   -mapper cat \
                   -reducer cat
```

step 4- move the output to the input folder

```
hadoop fs -mv output/part-00000 input/large_file.txt
```

step 5 - remove output

```
 hadoop fs -rm -R output/
```

step 6 - remove all the files from tmp

```
hadoop fs -rm tmp/*.txt
```

Create a shell script from step 2 till step 6 and schedule it to run at regular intervals to merge the smaller files at regular intervals (may be for every minute  based on your need)

**Steps to schedule a cron job for merging small files**

step 1: create a shell script **/home/abc/mergejob.sh** with the help of above steps (2 to 6)

**important note:** you need to specify the absolute path of hadoop in the script to be understood by cron

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/abc/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -mv input/*.txt tmp
wait
/home/abc/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop jar /home/abc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar \
                   -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
                   -input "/user/abc/input" \
                   -output "/user/abc/output" \
                   -mapper cat \
                   -reducer cat
wait
/home/abc/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -mv output/part-00000 input/large_file.txt
wait
/home/abc/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -rm -R output/
wait
/home/abc/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -rm tmp/*.txt
```

step 2: schedule the script using cron to run every minute using cron expression

a) edit crontab by choosing an editor

```
>crontab -e
```

b) add the following line at the end and exit from the editor

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/abc/mergejob.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The merge job will be scheduled to run for every minute.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you Addy,Samson,and Andrew for taking your time and posting the answer... Andy if possible can you please post the shell script and scheduling part.Iam very new to shell script and scheduling.

Comment: @Raj- updated the scheduling part in the answer, hope it will be helpful

Comment: @Aditya I copied the hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar into HDFS and gave it's path in the script. But, I got a Not a valid JAR exception while executing the above script.

Answer (score 2):

@Andrew pointed you to a solution that *was* appropriate 6 years ago, in a batch-oriented world.
But it's 2016, you have a micro-batch data flow running and require a **non-blocking** solution.

That's how I would do it:

- create an EXTERNAL  table with 3 partitions, mapped on 3 directories
  e.g. `new_data`, `reorg` and `history`
- feed the new files into `new_data`
- implement a job to run the batch compaction, and run it periodically

Now the batch compaction logic:

1. make sure that no SELECT query will be executed while the compaction is  running, else it would return duplicates
2. select all files that are ripe for compaction *(define your own
   criteria)* and **move** them from `new_data` directory to `reorg`
3. **merge** the content of all these `reorg` files, into a new file in `history` dir *(feel free to GZip it on the fly, Hive will recognize the `.gz` extension)*
4. **drop** the files in `reorg`

So it's basically the old 2010 story, except that your existing data flow can continue dumping new files into `new_data` while the compaction is safely running in separate directories. And in case the compaction job crashes, you can safely investigate / clean-up / resume the compaction without compromising the data flow.

---

By the way, I am not a big fan of the 2010 solution based on a "Hadoop Streaming" job -- on one hand, "streaming" has a very different meaning now; on the second hand, "Hadoop streaming" was useful in the old days but is now out of the radar; on the gripping hand [*] you can do it quite simply with a Hive query e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE blahblah PARTITION (stage='history')
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM blahblah
WHERE stage='reorg'
;
```

With a couple of `SET some.property = somevalue` before that query, you can define what compression codec will be applied on the result file(s), how many file(s) you want (or more precisely, how big you want the files to be - Hive will run the merge accordingly), etc.

Look into https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties under `hive.merge.mapfiles` and `hive.merge.mapredfiles` (or `hive.merge.tezfiles` if you use TEZ) and `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize` and then `hive.exec.compress.output` and `mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec` -- plus `hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat` to reduce the number of Map containers since your input files are quite small.

[*] *very old SF reference here* :-)